# How to display a "What's new" dialog on every new version of my app

Tags: application-development, python, gtk

I'd like to be able to present a dialog that runs at the start of my application and shows the new features this new version implements.

This dialog should only run once, and not be showed again until the user upgrades to a higher version of the app.

I'm not looking for a snippet, but rather for a suggestion on how to do this.

What's the best way to display such a dialog, so that it appears only once on the first run after the app has been upgraded?

Answer (score 3):

Pseudo-code:

```
version = 1

if settings.read("lastVersion", default=0) < version:
    showDialog()
    settings.save("lastVersion")
```

Then you just update the version variable for each new version, and done. In text: simply use a setting to save the last version, and if the program version is newer, show the dialog and update the setting.

Answer (score 1):

One idea jump to mind. Write the version number into whatever you use as your config store (dconf, dot file, etc...). On start up, check if that value matches the current program version. If not, display your dialog and bump the version number in the config. You could also ship your changelog in a parse-able format so you can only display changes from versions greater than what is in the config.

Comment: Do you happen to know if there is any standard or de-facto standard for parseable changelogs?